# Push_back implementation for a (heterogenous) set of vectors

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, containers

Say I have a struct (or a class) as shown below:

```
struct _particle {
std::vector<float> vx , vy;
std::vector<int> id;
std::vector<double> rx, ry;
};
typedef struct _particle particle;
particle p;
```

This is a struct of arrays (vectors). Now I want to push_back one particle with given vx, vy, id, rx, ry data values to this. Naively, I would apply a push_back to each of the vectors in a particle object `p`.

```
p.vx.push_back(vx_val); p.vy.push_back(vy_val); ...
```

But this means that any developer who wishes to add a new field (a new vector) would have to manually add a `push_back` call everytime a new particle data needs to be added.

Is it possible to implement a `push_back` in such a way that it loops through all elements in the `particle` struct and adds to the tail of the vectors?

The only way I am able to solve this is by creating a list of references to the vectors within the `particle` struct. But this is more C like and may be not in the style of C++. Is there a standard/neat way to achieve this?

Comment: The obvious solution is to use AoS and not SoA

Comment: Obviously. This is what I have been using and it is very elegant to work this way. But I am facing major Cache misses and want to use SIMD as much as possible.

Comment: Understood. You mention that a developer would need to add a new push back every time a particle is added. What does that look like? Wouldn't they also need to add a parameter to that function?

Comment: Yes. They would need to supply the parameters. But these paramters could be in the form of a struct, or of the same type ( `particle`) with vector length of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you try, you have to keep track of member names and their types. So you cannot have a method which will all automatically adds the `push_back` to the new member.

A little easy way I can think of, is storing pointer to the members in a tuple and use a function with parameter pack to go through the pointers and push back all. This will save the push_back but you still need to add new pointers to the tuple when new members added.

Comment: This is close to what I tried. But I could only think of a C style way of doing it. How would you create a pointer tuple and may be cast the pointers to a single type in C++? could you please provide a (pseudo) code?

Comment: Would `std::tuple` of `std::reference_wapper` be a good implementation, then?

Comment: Sure developers would need to keep track of the members. But the question is to reduce code changes, so that all the member vectors are of the same size whether the developer is aware of a new member or not.

Comment: @P.Nair std::tuple<vector<int>*, vector<int>*> and so on. Or reference instead of pointer. Tuple has its size so you know the number of members and all use the same push_back

Comment: @P.Nair it's too late for me, I'll add an example tomorrow.

Comment: please do so. My only worry is if using references like vector<int>* is a good idea if I plan to pass around the data (only pointer to data) to other functions.